# How to Get specific keys of multi-dimensional array with Arr::only()

Tags: laravel

Can I use [`Arr::only()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-array-only) to get specific keys in multidimensional array ?

Dot notation doesn't work in this case:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

$array = ['name' => 'Desk', 'model.small.price' => 100, 'orders' => 10];

$slice = Arr::only($array, ['name', 'model.small.price']);

// ['name' => 'Desk', 'model.small.price' => 100]
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-array-only see this if it helps

Comment: what Laravel version are you using? it works fine in Laravel 8